# C - Array is not working when copying files from text file

Tags: arrays, c, file

For some reason when I copy words from a file to an array, the last element is replacing all the contents from the previous indexes; however, I tested that the array is working fine before going throught the 'file loop' by adding text to index 0 and 1. Please take a look:

```
FILE *file = fopen("words.txt", "r");
 if (file == NULL){
    printf("...\n");
    return false;
 }

char *words[172805];

//Array test
words[0] = "abc";
words[1] = "bcde";
printf("%s, %s\n", words[0], words[1]);

// Copy words in text document to 'words' array.
while (!feof(file)) {
    if (fgets(arraywordindic, 15, file) != NULL) {
        //Remove \n from word in arraywordindic
        arraywordindic[strcspn(arraywordindic, "\n")] = '\0';
        words[i] = arraywordindic;
        printf("%s\n", words[i]);
        i++;
        if (i == 4) {break;}
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("%s, ", words[i]);
}

fclose(file);
```

The output of above code is:

abc bcde

A

AA

AAH

AAHED

AAHED, AAHED, AAHED, AAHED,

Do you happen to know why this is happening? Thank you.

Comment: Why `172805`? That's an unusually specific number.

Comment: The number of words I need to store in the array is 172806.

Comment: That's the sort of assumption you don't want to make in C. You're also one short if that's the case. It's better to dynamically allocate more and more memory as necessary using something like `realloc` or a linked-list structure.

Comment: Thank you. Not for this exercise, that is all the amount of words we need. For dynamic arrays I use memory allocation functions instead as you are mentioning.

Comment: If you need *N* elements you need an array defined as size `[N]`, not `N-1`, that is an array like `int x[10]` holds 10 elements numbered 0 through 9.

Comment: Oh, I got it now, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're setting pointers to exactly the same buffer over and over. You need to copy the strings, or in other words:

```
words[i] = strdup(arraywordindic);
```

In C when you say `char* x = y` this does **not** copy the contents of that string, it copies the *pointer to the string*.